# Python 3 Overriding method with different signature in the derived class

Tags: python-3.x

i want to override a method from a base class in the derived class.

I don't have access to the code of the base class, so i must inherit from it and have to override the method.

The overriding method needs to call a function with any number of arguments, passed as argument therefore i have to change the methods signature.

But i get the following error when i try to run the following code:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Example code:

```
# I don't have access to this code:
# _____________________________
class Base:
    def run(self):
        pass
# _____________________________



# Only to the following:

class Sub(Base):
    def run(self, func, *args):
        func(*args)


def call_me(test1, test2):
   print(test1+test2)


test = Sub
test.run(call_me, "test1 ", "test2")
```

Any suggestions how i can solve this problem?

I want the method "run" to be able to call any function with unkown numbers of arguments

**---------  EDIT  ---------**

Ok sorry, i found the solution:

It was just a terrible typo - my bad!

The typo was missing braces in the following statement:

```
test = Sub
```

must be:

```
test = Sub()
```